# Spring scatter gather release strategy

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Can someone explain me how release-strategy-expression used in scatter gatherer works. I have completely omitted this property and I do see that different threads are still processing the requests. Is this property required only if we have defined the custom aggregation to release the message group and aggregate them.

Answer (score 0):

The Scatter Gather is a complex component. It is combination of `PublishSubscribeChannel` or `RecipientListRouter` and an `Aggregator`. Both `PublishSubscribeChannel` and router have an `applySequence` property to populate default sequence details. This default information could be used by the mentioned aggregator to correlate and release message group using its default strategies.

If you don't rely on default sequence details generation, you indeed need to provide some custom  release strategy.

If you release strategy is not based on a full group gathering, then it is indeed possible that some processes for scattered messages are still in progress even if you have already released a gathered group. We just fully don't have control over those processes and that aggregator is just ignoring late replies.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#scatter-gather

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So does this mean if we omit release-strategy-expression then the aggregator will still aggregate messages using default strategy. What is the default strategy.

Comment: The `SimpleSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` - count number of messages in a group according `sequenceSize` header populated upfront by some sequencer component. In this case recipient list router or publish-subscribe channel.